# PCI card electromechanical specification

Tags: mechanical, pci

I am making an old PCI (5V) form factor card for a product, and am having a hard time finding any sort of reliable drawing showing the official dimensions of the gold fingers, key cutouts, and their relationship to the PCI mounting bracket.

Was there an official PCI specification released that I just am unable to find on the internet?  Is there some other resource that has these?  I am trying to avoid the mistakes that would come about from manually measuring PCI cards I have in house.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is a official specification, several versions in fact.

There is also a book about the PCI bus **PCI Bus Demystified** that is informative.

The specification is published by https://pcisig.com and can be ordered from them or you can search for it and ... https://www.ics.uci.edu/~harris/ics216/pci/PCI_22.pdf

PS. I used the search terms "PCI mechanical specification".

Answer (score 0):

> Was there an official PCI specification released that I just am unable to find on the internet?

Yes. Officially, you need to be a member of the PCI-SIG to download any of the PCI-related specifications - see [here](https://pcisig.com/specifications).

An example of the specification which contains details of the mechanical & connector parts of the original PCI cards, is called: **PCI Local Bus Specification Revision 3.0**

You should be successful searching for that.